# How are people using Google App-Engine apps with their own domains?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been fooling around with the Google App Engine for a few days and I have a little hobby application that I want to write and deploy.

However I'd like to set it up so that users are **not** directly accessing the app via appspot.com.

Is hosting it through Google Apps and then pointing it at my own domain the only way to go?  I looked at that a little bit and it seemed like a pain to implement but maybe I'm just missing something.

My other thought was to write the app-engine piece as a more generic web-service.

Then I could have the user-facing piece be hosted anywhere, written in any language, and have it query the appspot.com url.

Anyone have any luck with the web-service approach?

Comment: Can you clarify why it is you don't want to use Google Apps? It doesn't cost anything, and as others have pointed out, you don't have to use any of the services. If you already have a google apps domain, you can just add this one as an alias and map it to the App Engine app, too.

Comment: It just seemed like an extra layer of complexity that would nice to avoid (if possible).  Maybe I'm just being to picky about the choices presented by a free service.

Comment: I came up with a scheme that I like and wrote some blog posts about it.  I'll post links to the posts if anyone is interested.

Comment: That would be helpful - can you?

Comment: Sure.  I wrote 3 pretty simple posts about it.

Comment: http://mark.biek.org/blog/2008/10/foray-into-the-google-app-engine/

Comment: http://mark.biek.org/blog/2008/10/comment-engine-round-1/

Comment: http://mark.biek.org/blog/2008/10/comment-engine-round-2/

Comment: Let me know if you want to see the actual code.  It's not pretty but it's a starting point :)

Comment: Google Apps is NOT free, it costs $50 per user per year.

Comment: Standard Edition is free: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html - and that's all you need in order to map a domain to an App Engine app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we're now at the end of 2017 and things are a lot different regarding App Engine and custom domains. It's easy now!

Go to the app engine dashboard for your app and choose Settings, then go to the Custom Domains tab. From there, choose `Add custom domain`.

The tricky part is that Google needs to verify that you control the domain, so they ask you to put a TXT record in the DNS for your domain. Once you do that and Google it, you become "verified" as the owner of the domain.

After that, Google will give you a bunch of A and AAAA (for IP6) records to put in your DNS. Once you've done that, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 8):

The reason Google Apps is required is because you need somewhere to a) verify you own the domain (otherwise, you might point it at app engine, then I might hijack it by adding it to my account) and b) set up domain mappings (which subdomains point to which of your appengine apps).

Since this stuff already exists in Apps, it seems silly to duplicate it in AppEngine.

As has been pointed out, it doesn't cost anything, and you do not need to "move" anything to Google. You simple created a cname record with a random name to verify you own the domain, and a cname for the subdomain you wish to point at App Engine. This only takes a few minutes, and once it's done, it's done forever.

Note: If you host your site elsewhere and use webservices, you need to scale the site/frontend. If you host on app engine, you get this for free :-)

I wrote an article on my blog about redirecting *.appspot.com domains to your custom domain to keep your branding:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/12/redirecting-requests-from-appid-appspot-com-to-a-custom-domain

Comment: +1 for providing an explanation *why* Google Apps usage is actually required, despite question hasn't been active for a couple of month.

Answer (score 7):

To do this, I believe you need to be using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) and have a custom domain setup for Google Apps.  Then, you [deploy your app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains) into your Google Apps domain.

Comment: Hurmmm...I'd love to not have to use Google Apps.  It'll be interesting to see if anyone has had usuccess with other approaches.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be optional based on the "deploy your app" link above.

Comment: You don't have to use Google Apps, right? Sign up and don't use any of its services.

Comment: I still don't see the objection. It's free, and you can use it solely for mapping App Engine apps to domains if you want.

Comment: @NickJohnson: My objection is that it's just a really poor user experience.

Answer (score 4):

Here is google's official instructions on how to do that:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

I have used this process for a couple of sites and it is easy and painless, provided you have control on the DNS records for your domain (you should).

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using `request.getRequestURI()` method. If the URL doesn't include your domain, just redirect it to the desired URL using

```
resp.sendRedirect("<your domain>")
```

Otherwise load a error page using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("<error-page>").forward(request, response);
```